# How to access GPIO from kernel space? (zynq-microzed board)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, zynq

I am using `zynq-microzed` board and I want to access `GPIO` with `kernel space.`

Can anyone please tell me how can i attempt doing this?

Comment: This is hardware-dependent.  Please describe your hardware.

Comment: @ken, I have zynq-microzed board (ARM).

Comment: You need to check if your kernel version and arch/platform/board conform to Linux conventions for GPIO. See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/gpio.txt?v=3.0  For instance Atmel ARM had at91_gpio routines, and then switched to using generic gpio routines in later 3.x kernels.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This is from the Zynq-7000. I believe it's largely the same.

Assuming you're using a devicetree, this is an example entry (in the devicetree):

```
gpio-device {
    compatible = "gpio-control";
    gpios = <&gpio0 54 0>; //(Add 32 to get the actual pin number. This is GPIO 86)
};
```

And you need to state in the driver that you're compatible with the devicetree entry (look at other drivers to see where to put this line):

```
.compatible = "gpio-control"
```

In your driver, include `#include <linux/gpio.h>` and read the pin from the devicetree:

```
struct device_node *np = pdev->dev.of_node;
int pin;

pin = of_get_gpio(np, 0);
if (pin < 0) {
    pr_err("failed to get GPIO from device tree\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Request the use of the GPIO:

```
int ret = gpio_request(pin, "Some name"); //Name it whatever you want
```

And set it's direction:

```
int ret = gpio_direction_output(pin, 0); //The second parameter is the initial value. 0 is low, 1 is high.
```

Afterwards, set the value like so:

```
gpio_set_value(pin, 1);
```

For input:

```
ret = gpio_direction_input(pin);
value = gpio_get_value(pin);
```

Free the GPIO when you're finished with it (including on error!):

```
gpio_free(pin);
```

At the end of the day, a good method is to `grep` around the kernel to find drivers that do what you want. In fact `grep -r gpio <<kernel_source>>` will tell you everything in this answer and more.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link: [enter link description here](https://lwn.net/Articles/532714/)

Summarizing:

There is an include file for working with GPIOs:

```
#include <linux/gpio.h>
```

GPIOs must be allocated before use:

```
int gpio_request(unsigned int gpio, const char *label);
```

And GPIO can be returned to the system with:

```
void gpio_free(unsigned int gpio);
```

Configure GPIO as Input/Output:

```
int gpio_direction_input(unsigned int gpio);
int gpio_direction_output(unsigned int gpio, int value);
```

Operations:

```
int gpio_get_value(unsigned int gpio);
void gpio_set_value(unsigned int gpio, int value);
```

Regards.